# Logic for JQuery Slideshow

Tags: jquery

I want to implement a vertical slide show using JQuery. I am using a vertical reel(div) which in turn contains images one by one i am decrementing the the reel Top position by image size every 2 second which is working fine but when i reach to the last image i am not able to implement the logic to start the reel from first images. if my explanation is not clear i am appending my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        setInterval(SlideImage, 2000);
    });

    function SlideImage() {
        $("#imgReel").animate({ "marginTop": "-=300px" }, 1000, function() { });
    }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    img
    {
        width: 600px;
        height: 300px;
    }
    .imgContainer
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 620px !important;
        height: 300px !important;
    }
    div
    {
        width: 620px;
    }
    .current
    {
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .next
    {
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .imgReel
    {
        width: 620px !important;
    }
    .
</style>
```

```
<body>
<div id="imgContainer" class="imgContainer">
    <div id="imgReel" class="imgReel">
        <div class="current">
            <img src="Images/Summerwave.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="Images/Sunlight_and_the_Wild_Forest_Floor.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="Images/Sunset.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="Images/Swimming_with_the_fishys.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="Images/Tearing_Apart.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="Images/Teaser.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="Images/Terra_Nova.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use other approach: let `#imgReel` fixed, and resize the elements:

Moving the imgReel to the bottom, will make that if you do an `slideUp` to the element in the top, appending before this first element at the very bottom (after the last element), you'll have the effect that the reel is moving, disappearing the top of the current image first.

In code, using the plugin [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo):

```
var $reel = null;
function init() {
    $reel = $("#imgReel")
    // Keep the first element as first shown, now that we're going to take the reel to the bottom
    $reel.children("div:first").insertAfter($reel.children("div:last"))
    // Move to the bottom using scrollTo or whatever you want:
    $reel.scrollTo("max")
}

function next() {
    // Clone the first element (not visible) at the end
    var $topElement = $reel.children("div:first")
    var $bottomElement = $topElement.clone().appendTo($reel)

    // Hide the top element (cloned now at the bottom) and remove it when it's done
    $topElement.slideUp(1000, function() { $(this).remove() })

    // Mark the next 'current'
    $reel.children(".current").removeClass("current");
    $bottomElement.addClass("current");
}
```

On the other hand, if you don't want to make an infinite loop, and keeping your approach, using [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) is as simple as this:

```
funnction next() {
    var $current = $reel.find("div.current").removeClass("current")
    var $next = $current.next()
    if(!$next.length) $next = $reel.children("div:first")
    $reel.scrollTo($next.addClass("current"), 1000)
}

function prev() {
    var $current = $reel.find("div.current").removeClass("current")
    var $next = $current.prev()
    if(!$next.length) $next = $reel.children("div:last")
    $reel.scrollTo($next.addClass("current"), 1000)
})
```

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can either move back to the top of the reel, or move a viewed `div` to the end of the reel.

The move back to the beginning you could make pretty by fading the box to some color, move to the beginning (the user doesn't see this happening), and fade the color out. This way the user knows he is looking again at the same pictures.